# Detect when user takes a screenshot in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, screenshot

So in this maze kind of game I'm making, I will show the maze to the player for 30 seconds.
What I don't want is that the player taking screenshot of the maze.

I want to do something like Snapchat, or Instagram, how it detects when you take a screenshot of a snap/story.

I'm using C#. It can also prevent user to take screenshot. I don't mind.

Is there a possible way to detect when the user takes screenshots or prevent it in Unity?

Comment: Who cares if they take a screenshot? If the user wants to ruin the intended experience then so be it.

Comment: @BrandonMiller I was thinking the same, unless there will be a scoring system against other players.

Comment: I was planning to make it multiplier. Well, I gotta figure out a solution I guess :)

Comment: Is it multiplayer as in two players trying to solve the same maze at the same time, or is it just a leaderboard? Are the mazes procedurally generated?

Comment: @BrandonMiller Two or more players solving the puzzle at the same time, and the mazes will be generated randomly.

Comment: Then you honestly don't have much to worry about. If player A takes a screenshot of the maze, then he will take more time studying the maze on a screenshot while player B is actually solving it. This is especially true for procedurally generated mazes. Taking into account that the user will also have to put the app into background in order to study the screenshot, it would be more reliable if you could catch the event that fires when the user does that instead.

Comment: @BrandonMiller oh, maybe I could kick the player if he doesn't "focus" on the app. Yeah, that's another solution. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. The only problem is if the user gets a phone call and answers or something like that, but seeing as this is a speed-based game, you should probably kick them anyways. Nobody likes competing against an AFK player.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166273/discussion-between-qedized-and-brandon-miller).

Comment: Fact is, if the user wants to cheat, he won't capture his screen, he will use a second device to take a picture. Make sense since you can't have the picture open and the game. But you can have the game and the other device displaying the picture. So your endeavor trying to prevent the screen capture seems pointless.

Comment: @Everts I might make a program to track down players that mostly win, and when it catches them, I would take a look on their playstyle. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You should store scores and actions on server. This will give you an average score. From there, you can define what can be a margin. Anyone above could be cheating. This way you don't have to track every single player, just those suspicious. At some point, Angry Birds had a Chrome hack giving unlimited tricks to the player. One day, they wipe all of those with suspicious score (and probably no IAP). So this is quite common I would say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once had to do something similar. If you just want to do what snapchat did then it can be done but remember that as long as the app is running on anyone's device instead of your server, it can be de-compiled, modified and compiled again so this screenshot detection can be circumvented.

First of all you need to know this about Apple's rule:

> 2.5.9 Apps that alter or disable the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, or other native
>   user interface elements or behaviors will be rejected.

So, the idea of altering what happens when you take a screenshot is eliminated.

What you do is start the game, do the following when you are showing the show the maze to the player for 30 seconds:

**On iOS:**

Continuously check if the player presses the **power** and the **home** button at the-same time. If this happens, restart the game and show the maze to the player for 30 seconds again. Do it over and over again until player stops doing it. You can even **disconnect** or **ban** the player if you detect power + the home button press.

**On Android:**

Continuously check if the player presses the the **power** and **volume down** buttons at the-same time. Perform the-same action described above.

You **cannot** just do this with **C#**. You have to use make plugins for both iOS and Android devices. The plugin should use Java to the the detection on android and Object-C to do the detection for iOS. This is because the API required is not available in **C#**. You can then call the Java and Objective-C functions from C#.

---

**Other improvement to make:**

- Check or external display devices and disable them when you are
  showing the maze to the player for 30 seconds. Enable them back
  during this time.
- When you detect the screenshot button press as described above,
  *immediate take your own screenshot too*. Loop through images on the player's picture gallery and load all the images taken that day.
  Compare it with the screenshot you just took and see if they match.
  If they do, you are now very sure that the player is trying to cheat.
  Take action like banning the player, restarting the game or even
  trolling the player by sending their screenshot to the other player. You can also use it as a proof to show that the user is cheating when they complain after being banned.
- Finally, you can even go deeper by using *OpenCV*. When you are
  showing the player the maze for 30 seconds, start the front camera of
  the device and use *OpenCV* to continuously check if any object other
  than the player's head is in front of the camera. If so, then the
  player is trying to take a screenshot with another device. Take
  action immediately. You can use machine language to train this.

How far to go depends on how much time you want to spend and how much you care about player's cheating online. The only thing to worry about is players de-compiling the game and removing those features but it is worth implementing.

> My Android phone takes screenshots differently. I swipe down from the
>   top of the screen and select the "Capture" option.

Nothing is always the-same on Android. This is different on some older or different Android devices. *You can detect swipe patterns on the screen*. The best way to do this is to build a profile that handles each Android device from different manufactures.

For those commenting, this is possible to do. You must do it especially if it is a multiplayer game. Just because a game can be hacked does not mean that a programmer should not implement basic hack prevention mechanism. Basic hack prevention mechanism should be implemented then improved as you get feedback from players.

Comment: My Android phone takes screenshots differently. I swipe down from the top of the screen and select the "Capture+" option.

Comment: not to mention the countless other ways to take screenshots without an event.

Comment: My old phone was both volume buttons. This isn't a catch-all solution.

Comment: This is the best solution I got so far. Yeah, I'm probably going to not do this though since as a lot of people said, there are lots of other ways to take a screenshot. I will probably try to figure out another way of giving hints / tips. Thanks again.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad, jdmdevdotnet  and BrandonMiller That's true. Android devices are always different when it comes to features. My answer covered the most basic way to take screenshot on those devices. OP can build a profile for Android devices to handle others.

Comment: @Qedized Added more details. This is possible to do but may be complicated depending on how far you want to take it. The biggest thing to worry about is people modifying the app itself and removing those checks but totally ignoring online cheaters because it is changeling to implement means less players you'll have. This is the biggest issue game developers face these days.

Comment: @Programmer Haha wow, thanks a lot. I do not think I will take it that far, but I'm sure there will be people that will. I think this answer will be beneficial for them. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't detect this reliably. They also could make a photo with a digi cam. Furthermore there are endless ways to create a screenshot and the os has no "callback" to inform an application about that. You could try to detect the "print screen" key but as I said there are other screenshot / screen recording tools which could use any hotkey or no hotkey at all. I have never used Snapchat but it seems it's not safe either.

There are even monitors and video projectors which have a freeze mode to keep the current image. You could also run your browser in a virtual machine. There you can actually freeze the whole virtual PC or take screen shots from the virtual screen and an application running inside the VM has no way to even detect or prevent that.

Comment: Um, I saw this too...
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1017115/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-screenshot-is-being.html

Comment: Yet you ask on here? You knew the answer before asking?

Comment: I ask it because I was curious. Only one person answered it, and no one told anything else. I wanted to make sure. Thanks anyways :)